# Is there a reason for so much repetition in Angular directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Recently I have been coming across a lot of repetition in Angular.

**Example:**

ngShow **vs** ngHide
Pristine **vs** Dirty
valid **vs** invalid

Won't `ng-show="!condition"` and `ng-show="condition"` cover all cases for showing and hiding content within the view?

Having both ngShow and ngHide directive seems in AngularJs as pointless as having an if and an ifNot statement in JavaScript.

Is there a reason for doing this? When should custom directives be written like this?

Comment: Semantics. Sometimes it's just easier to understand that something should be hidden if some condition is true.

Comment: I guess it have more to do with the semantics, using `ng-show` with a not `!` might look a bit confusing to next developer.

Comment: It's all about readability. `ng-hide="condition"` is easier to read and understand than `ng-show="!condition"`. It's just an opinion that you happen not to share with the developers.